# Automated Testing for C/C++ GUI Applications

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, automated-tests

I have a GUI application written in C/C++ using gcc. I need some recommendations for writing an automated test system for it. What tools/scripting should be used? The application runs on Windows.

Comment: There is a lot of choice for tools that automate Windows GUI apps. So please provide more info e.g. what is your budget?  do you use custom gui controls? do you have a preference for scripting languages, what is the skill level of the people creating the tests etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation is PyWinAuto, open source tool, python based tests (fast and easy to develop) and work on win32 level.
http://pywinauto.openqa.org/

Comment: Thanks santi it seems to be quite resembling to http://www.autoitscript.com/ but kind of giving more control than autoit.

Answer (score 3):

We have used [TestComplete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestComplete) here, with some success.

Comment: Our GUI application was written in Borland C++ Builder which sometimes uses some obscure controls not fully supported by TestComplete. But generally TestComplete performed well.

Comment: We've also used this before and really liked it.  It has some great features.

Comment: Thanks for your response qrdl , i have looked into TestComplete it seems to be having certain limitations which can reduce as you said amount of success. However i have found AutoIT script which is also nice http://www.autoitscript.com/

Answer (score 0):

Can't go past [White](http://white.codeplex.com/) now. Although I think it has some shortfalls for 64 bit apps.